# jquery tablesorter textExtraction

Tags: tablesorter

I am using the jquery tablesorter plugin

webpage is here:  http://redbluffbullsale.com/bulls-listings

I have a complex textExtraction function defined below:

```
var jgExtraction = function(node) {
  if (node.childNodes[0].length > 0) {
    return node.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
  } else {
    return node.innerHTML;
  }
}

jQuery('#bullsTable').tablesorter({
  textExtraction: 'jgExtraction',
  headers: {
    0 : {sorter: false},
    13: {sorter: 'digit'},
    14: {sorter: 'digit'}
  }
});
```

In a few of the columns (13 & 14) there is data that can be in the following format:

number (ex: 0.9, 2.3, 4, -2, -2.5, etc)
text (the letter I) plus number (I+2.3, I-0.9, I+1.4, etc)
plus sign with number (+2.4, +3.1, +0.9, etc)

On the server I am controlling the column data so that if it is a number or a negative number it is dumped in the <td>, but if the column data has an I+, I-, or a +, then that the column has the I+, I- or + separated from the number with <span> tags, like:

```
<td>-1.4</td>
<td>I+<span>1.6</span></td>
<td>I-<span>3.4</span></td>
<td>+<span>2.2</span></td>
```

My jgExtraction should return the innerHTML if there is no span child node, or return the contents of the childNode[0] (span) if it exists.  The sorting is not working for the columns with I+ or I-.  You can see what is wrong by checking out the URL above.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in the above code.

- The name of the text extraction function shouldn't be added as a string

  ```
  textExtraction: 'jgExtraction', // wrong
  textExtraction: jgExtraction,   // correct
  ```
- Within the `jgExtraction` function, check the length of child nodes, not the length of the first item

  ```
  if (node.childNodes[0].length > 0) { // wrong 
  if (node.childNodes.length > 1) {    // correct
  ```
- A text node will return `undefined` when checking its innerHTML. It should be targetting the span anyway:

  ```
  return node.childNodes[0].innerHTML // wrong
  return node.childNodes[1].innerHTML; // target the span
  ```

Here is the modified code & [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/278/):

```
var jgExtraction = function(node) {
    if (node.childNodes.length > 1) {
        return node.childNodes[1].innerHTML;
    } else {
        return node.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

If you are interested, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) which will allow you to sort empty table cells to the top, bottom or treat them as having a value of zero (the default behavior) - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sort-empty.html)

Comment: Can you please have a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546186/tablesorter-and-multi-textextraction-in-jquery ?

Comment: For searchers: if you want to exclude node to filter make sure your all data in same <td></td> Node == <td>
var myTextExtraction = function (node, table, cellIndex) {              
                return $(node).find('.news-summary').text() && $(node).find('.news-header').text();