# Tablesorter and multi textExtraction in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have this table which has TableSorter plugin.

[Jsbin #1](http://jsbin.com/azijap/2/edit)

[image]

However - I want for column #1 ( second zero based) to be sorted by the <strike>*first char*</strike>  *second char*  as digit !)

example :

```
4134 (I dont care about the other digits order - just the first one which is here=1)
22230 //2
242   //4
67    //7
28    //8
992222 //9
```

So I created **another** textExtraction function :  ( which is going to be applied only at the first column)

```
    var myExtraction = function(node) {
  return parseInt($(node).substring(1))
}
```

and **added another** object to the ctor which is only for column #1.(0'based).

```
...,{
    textExtraction: myExtraction,
    headers: {
        1: {
            sorter: 'digit'
        } 
    }
}
```

However it doesn't ( <strike>[jsbin#2 is here](http://jsbin.com/azijap/5/edit)</strike>  [new jsbin](http://jsbin.com/azijap/15/edit)) work and i'm pretty sure this is not the way.

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure you need the custom `myExtraction` at all. Just change the sorter for that column to `'text'` instead of `'digit'` and it should work when you specify it with the rest of the headers.

**Edit**

If you want the *second* digit to be used for sorting:

```
var myExtraction = function(node) {
  return $(node).text().substring(1);
}

jQuery('#bullsTable').tablesorter(
{
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        1: {
            sorter: 'text'
        },
        13: {
            sorter: 'digit'
        }, 
        14: {
            sorter: 'digit'
        }
    },
      textExtraction: jgExtraction,
      textExtraction: {
         1: myExtraction
      }
}
```

I updated your [jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/azijap/17/edit).

Note: you were using an old version of tablesorter that didn't appear to support `textExtraction`. I updated the `<script>` tag and it works.

Comment: +1 and @RoyiNamir since you specifically asked me, this is the correct way to do it - I've also updated [your demo](http://jsbin.com/azijap/13/edit)

Comment: @Mottie ( and mccannf) , my sample works cause this is how text is working. I ;m so sorry but since it is working by default - I should have asked about the **second digit**. not the first one. I just want to know how can I create ANOTHER text extraction. I hope you understand

Comment: @RoyiNamir That doesn't make any sense. Doing something like that will only confuse the users of your site.

Comment: @Mottie it is not for my site. it is for learnning how to control the way it sorts. and to understand the difference between text Extraction VS adding filter.just for learning .

Comment: Well it's sorting the text by unicode value. So a space (32) will sort before an "a" (97) and a `&nbsp;` (160) - see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/QHEju/1/).

Comment: @Mottie I appreciate your help.But I seems to be misunderstood. :-)
**Ok :** what if the value **in the first TD**  is inside `<span>` and in the **second TD** the value is under `<div>` ? how would you create 2 textExtractions ?  ( thats the title of my question actually...). thanks for helping.

Comment: @mccannf  looking at your edit : does the first `textExtraction` will be for default , while the second one will be using the `myExtraction` ( for column #1) ? Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: @mccannf: You can't use the textExtraction option twice like that. The second one will override the first.

Comment: Oh! I forgot to mention that the original version of tablesorter does not support a textExtraction object `{ 1: function(){}, 2: function(){} }`. I've forked tablesorter and made many enhancements including this method - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html).

Comment: @mccannf It sorts just the visible rows in the grid...correct ? what if you have 1000 records and you have `prev` `next` buttons ?  this is where this plugin stops working....no ?

Comment: I think @Mottie is the best person to answer this - I would not have thought so, but he can comment...

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually, tablesorter stores all of the rows in an internal cache, which it sorts, then only displays the rows you want in the pager. The problem with this is if you add or remove a row and update the plugin, it only sees the currently displayed rows and loses all the others already in the cache. In my fork, I've included a pager option to only visibly hide rows, or you can use the `addRows` method which maintains the internal cache even if the rows don't exist in the table.

Comment: @Mottie I believe it is a client internal cache. which means I have to send it to the client at first place. this is not the correct way of doing it. ( IMHO).

Comment: @RoyiNamir Right, which is why my fork of tablesorter has two options to disable client side sorting and filtering when it is done server side, but still use the plugin for interaction.